# Disabling Landscape mode on the iPad, how does it affect App Store approval?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm currently working on an iPad app where we're considering disabling landscape mode.

Will this affect App Store approval in any way?

Comment: As long as you support both portrait orientations, you do not need to support landscape.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling landscape mode will not hinder your chances to get the app approved.

Indeed, landscape orientation only makes sense if your app requires it or has some advantage from using it; it is not mandatory. I have a couple of apps in the App Store that do not support landscape mode and I had no problem with the approval.

So, what you should be concerned about is if supporting both orientation (and autorotation) is beneficial for the user of your app. This is the only concern.

Answer (score 1):

NO. it is totally possible and reasonable that app support only one view mode. so you can go for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, It will not affect. you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's doubtful that you will be rejected as I can't find anything (anymore) in the

[App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

to suggest that it would be rejected.

I'm sure there used to be something in that document to suggest that apps may be rejected if they don't support all the orientations they can, which I where I expect your worry stems from.